# How can Rails Mailer view update an ActiveRecord record? (update_attribute not persisting)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

In my Foo model I have a method

```
def support_token_create_it_if_none_exists()
  self.my_support_token || self.create_a_support_token
end
```

In all my web code when I want the support token, I call `foobar.support_token_create_it_if_none_exists` and it returns a token (creating it first if needed).

If, however, in my Mailer view I want to do the same thing, eg, display the support token (and create it on the flyer if it does not yet exist)

```
...
Your token is #{@foobar.support_token_create_it_if_none_exists}
...
```

and in the email it displays a support token BUT if a token does not already exists it does NOT persist the token in Activerecord.

I assume there is some "Mailer view local copy" thing going on? If so, is there a way to have the update_attribute work even when in a mailer view?

(The easy workaround is ensure I always have the token created when I invoke the Mailer, but I'd like to understand what is happening so I don't make the same mistake.)

Answer (score 1):

What about checking for the token and creating it before the mailer is called?

Comment: Yes, that's the workaround I mentioned at the end. However I'm keenly interested in why it doesn't work as-is... if there is some local-copy-of-variables-in-mailers thing going on I need to understand that. If update_attributes never works in a mailer, or sometimes works under some conditions, that seems kind of important to understand going forward...